# Using preg_replace $limit randomly throughout string, not just first $limit matches?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm looking to `preg_replace` parts of a string only 3 times, however I don't want it to match and replace only the first 3 matches, but rather more varied throughout the entire string. Is this possible?

Example:

```
$post ['post_content']=preg_replace ('/ pizza /',' <a href="http://www.example.com">pizza</a> ',$post['post_content'],3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this (some tweaking might be needed):

```
$p = $post ['post_content'];
    if (preg_match_all('/ pizza /',$p, $matches)) {
    $rand = array_rand($matches[0], 2);
      foreach($rand as $rand_key) {
        $p=replace_num($matches[0][$rand_key], "XXX",$p, $rand_key+1);
      }

    }


    echo $p;

    function replace_num($from, $to, $string,$num) {
      $pos=-1;
      $i=0;
       while($pos!==false && $i<$num) {
            $pos = strpos($string, $from, $pos+1);
             $i++;
       }     
       if ($pos) {
         return substr($string, 0, $pos) . str_replace($from, $to, substr($string,$pos, strlen($from))) .  substr($string, $pos) ;

       }


    return $string;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I just needed a bit of help with the logic behind it all :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it.  But it will be a multi-step process.

First:  Do a `preg_match_all()` instead of a replace
Second: Do X number of array_rands to get the position of the 'pizza' string and replace one starting at that position (use substring).

I think you'll have to redo the match after each replacement, because the length of the string will change every time.

Don't forget to remove the index that is returned from the array rand so it isn't used twice.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the 4th parameter which is to limit n go thru the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) first

**$limit:**
The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).